# German Umlauts cause warning and error when reading shapefile with read_sf in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, choropleth

I am trying to plot a choropleth map from a shapefile in R, using read_sf for that shapefile. Unfortunately, R cannot read the German Umlauts properly. I get a whole bunch of warning messages. It is possible to plot a map, fortunately at least this works. But when I want to merge my data with the imported shapefile, and then plot the choropleth map, two of the sixteen German countries (Bundesländer) are dropped.

```
`# import shapefile
ger <- read_sf('geo_ger/vg2500_bld.shp')
ger`
```

```
This is the warning I get:

Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in gsub(chr, html_specials[[chr]], text, fixed = TRUE): input string 4 is invalid in this locale

Traceback:
1. tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
2. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
3. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
4. doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
5. withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler)
6. repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
7. repr_markdown.data.frame(obj)
8. repr_matrix_generic(obj, "\n%s\n\n%s%s\n", sprintf("|%%s\n|%s|\n", 
 .     underline), NULL, " <!--/--> |", " %s |", "%s", "|%s\n", 
 .     " %s |", " %s |", escape_fun = markdown_escape, rows = rows, 
 .     cols = cols, ...)
9. lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(r) {
 .     row <- escape_fun(slice_row(x, r))
 .     cells <- sprintf(cell, row)
 .     if (has_rownames) {
 .         row_head <- sprintf(row_head, escape_fun(rownames(x)[[r]]))
 .         cells <- c(row_head, cells)
 .     }
 .     sprintf(row_wrap, paste(cells, collapse = ""))
 . })
10. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
11. escape_fun(slice_row(x, r))
12. html_escape(values, do_spaces = FALSE)
13. gsub(chr, html_specials[[chr]], text, fixed = TRUE)
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Warning message in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
“input string 4 is invalid in this locale”
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'geojsonsf':
  method        from   
  print.geojson geojson
```

[This is what the map looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h58q8.png)

- What I could find out is that the shapefile is not encoded in UTF-8, but I do not know if this is a problem.
- I imported the same shapefile into Python, it worked properly, even the Umlauts.
- I also tried the solution `ger <- read_sf('geo_ger/vg2500_bld.shp') %>% st_transform(4326)`, but it did not work.
- Next I tried the rgdal package:

```
ger <- "geo_ger/vg2500_bld.shp"
shape_ger <- readOGR(ger, layer = 'vg2500_bld', use_iconv = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")
data_ger <- shape_ger@data
data_ger
```

It returns NA in those lines containing the Umlauts. So similar problem here.

I really prefer ggplot2 and would appreciate, if someone could help me.

This is my first question here, so please apologize if anything is not perfect :-)

Comment: Without a look at your shape file it's hard to figure out what might be the issue. I use German shapefiles from the BKG regularly without any issues reading the Umlate neither on Windows nor on Mac. But since the issue affects only two Bundesländer a quick and easy fix might be to recode the labels for the two Bundesländer to match the ones in your data.

Comment: The shapefile is from hub.arcgis.com: https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/ae25571c60d94ce5b7fcbf74e27c00e0/about I tried to find a. shp with the borders of the Bundesländer at  the BKG, but was slightly overwhelmed and could not find anything that fits. So, if you know where to find a shapefile with these borders at BKG, let me know.

Comment: This is the link to ones I use for Länder and Kreise: http://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/verwaltungsgebiete-1-1-000-000-stand-31-12-vg1000-31-12.html. Personally I use GK version.

Comment: FYI: I just had a look at the arcgis shaepfile. While I don't get any warning on my MAC when reading via `read_sf` the `"ü"` are unfortunately coded as `\xfc`. But a fix which worked in my case was to do `ger$GEN <- gsub("\xfc", "ü",  ger$GEN)`